# Unable to use breakpoints in an external framework in XCode 7.1 anymore

Tags: xcode, frameworks

Previously in XCode 6.4 we have a framework we are building and we link that into another project. I was then able to set the breakpoints in the frameworks XCode project and when launching the app from device not from debugger I was able to attached to the process and have all my breakpoints fire off!

In 7.0 and now 7.1 its gone. I am very curious is anyone else ran into this problem and might have solved for it? I have searched at length before posting so apologies if this is a duplicate...